# Api version for the URL when invoking an Azure IoT Direct method

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Based on the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/modules/invoke-method it seems the api_version parameter needs to be specified when invoking a direct method in an edge module. Where can I find this api_version parameter to specify in the URL? I looked in the device and module twins and cannot seem to find this parameter anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api_version` is currently the same for all IoT Hub API calls and is `2018-06-30`.

This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/iothub/

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to successfully Invoke the Direct method by setting the api_version to this value.